# How can discover controller name and method from a path on Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given a list of paths:

```
* /costumers/1
* /home
* /do/something/action-name
```

How can check the corresponding controller for these without need do the real call?

---

### Context:

I have a spreadsheet with many routes (exported from application analytic [New Relic]).
I'm try discover how routes doesn't are being called.
This check does not be does programmatically.

I'm using rails 4.2

Thank's

Comment: Programmatically?  Or just a way outside the app?

Comment: also, what version of rails?

Comment: @BillDoughty on 4.2. Don't be programmatically... In my context I have a list of routes on spreadsheet and need match with possible routes.

Comment: @Schwern's answer should be acceptable then.

Comment: Try playing with Rails.application.routes at runtime. Also you spelled customers wrong...unless you make apps for people who make costumes?

Answer (score 6):

You would do this with `rails routes` which will list all routes, verb, controller, and method.

You can search for certain routes with `-g`. `rails routes -g /costumers` for example. Don't search for `/costumers/1`. The 1 is not part of the route, it is the ID of the Costumer to show. Something like `/costumers/:id`. If your version does not support `-g`, pipe the output to `grep` `rake routes | grep /costumers` or use your pager `rake routes | less`.

You can also visit http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes

See [Rails Routing from the Outside In](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more.

Comment: @Schwen thanks for your reply! I forget about rails version. I add more context on my problem. I also try do your instructions and my rails version does not support that paramter on `rake routes` command.

Comment: @RafaelGomesFrancisco You can pipe the output to grep, `rake routes | grep /costumers` or [use a pager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_pager), `rake routes | less` or visit `http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes`.